# Passing useState value to React input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I  have created a React component that allows the user to filter a list by typing into an input, I have simplified the component into the below:

```
const value = filteredOptions
   .filter((option) => option.selected)
   .map((option) => option.label)
   .join(",");

const [input, setInput] = useState(value);

const handleSearch = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   setInput(e.target.value);
};

return (
<InputSearch 
   value={input}
   onChange={handleSearch}
/>
<SelectOption
   key={option.code}
   option={option}
   onClick={onValueChange}
/>

);
```

`value` is null by default (and is populated with a string value when selected) - this works. what I would like to do however is feed the `value` into my `input` state so that the `input` state can be updated either by typing into the input (which works currently) or by selecting a value.

Comment: where is you change handler for the select?

Comment: Can you share the other remaining code where the selection is happening, that's where you will need to update the value of the input.

Comment: In your `<InputSearch/>` component you could expose a prop called `setValue` and then pass `setInput` to this, you could then call this...

Comment: i've updated my post with the code to include the `<SelectOption />` component!